# ASP.NET Core server side validation failure causes Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.SerializableError

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I use [EmailAddress] attribute to validate email on server side. However, when I send an invalid email address, I receive a 400 status code response with no message instead of getting into my action method and seeing a ModelState Error.

Debug output simply says that Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.SerializableError is thrown.

Could anyone explain this, please?

Model:

```
public class LoginVm
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email cannot be empty.")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Email has an incorrect format.")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password cannot be empty.")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Action:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Authenticate([FromBody]LoginVm loginVm)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (loginVm.Email != "maksym@no.no" || loginVm.Password != "password")
        {
            return NotFound("There is no such user.");
        }

        return Ok();
    }
```

Debug output:

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:44381/api/accounts application/json 43
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService:Information: Policy execution successful.
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel:Information: Connection id "0HLF8QUE7VV6T", Request id "0HLF8QUE7VV6T:00000004": the application completed without reading the entire request body.
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Route matched with {action = "Authenticate", controller = "Account", page = ""}. Executing action WebApp.Controllers.AccountController.Authenticate (WebApp)
- 'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.1\System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
- 'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.1\System.Data.Common.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor:Information: Executing ObjectResult, writing value of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.SerializableError'.
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executed action WebApp.Controllers.AccountController.Authenticate (WebApp) in 78.8614ms
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 96.9303ms 400 application/json; charset=utf-8

Request:

```
POST http://localhost:58072/api/accounts HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:58072
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 47
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: https://localhost:44381
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9

{"email":"wrongemail","password":"wrongpassword"}
```

Comment: whats the request that you sent?

Comment: @Steve, http method, url, headers and body, basically everything that describes my request

Comment: you are posting to api/accounts. is that a controller or does it have a default method route?

Comment: Content-Length looks wrong. Did you compute that yourself? It could explain _the application completed without reading the entire request body_

Comment: @Steve, yes, it is a controller's action

Comment: @Jasen, content length is computed automatically, I am using Angular's HttpClient, so it is either done by Angular or the browser itself

Comment: @MaksymLapshyn post your /accounts action plz if it is

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The `[ApiController]` attribute provides [Automatic HTTP 400 responses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#automatic-http-400-responses-3).

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ProductsController : ControllerBase
```

> Validation errors automatically trigger an HTTP 400 response. The
> following code becomes unnecessary in your actions:
>
> ```
> if (!ModelState.IsValid)
> {
>     return BadRequest(ModelState);
> }
> ```

---

**How to turn off this feature**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
    });
   
    ...
}
```

[source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#disable-automatic-400-response-3)